# Two similar for loop outputs different value

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out the output of the following two loops. The only difference I notice is that the former use `var` and assigns a global scope and later create a local scope using `const`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1);
}
```

the output is `3 3 3` and `0 1 2`.
According to my shallow knowledge, the first loop has to output `0 1 2`.

If I print the value of `i` in the first loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1);
}
```

the output printed in the console by first `console.log(i)` is `0 1 2`. While in the one wrapped within `setTimeout` vary.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

`var` gets hoisted into the global scope, so when `setTimeout` is called it logs out whatever the value of `i` is when it is called, which would be `3` as the for loop has set `i` to `3` on its last iteration. Whereas `let` is scoped to the `for` loop and closes over the value of `i` on each iteration, thus printing `0 1 2`.